# How to stop celery worker process

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I am following [this](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/) along with the docs.

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

To start a worker. I have since made some changes to the Python, but realized that I need to restart a worker.

From the command line, I've tried:

```
 ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

But I can see that the worker is still running.

How can I kill it?

edit:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ sudo ps auxww | grep celeryd | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -HUP
kill: invalid argument H

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
```

edit 2:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep celery
ubuntu    9756  0.0  3.4 100868 35508 pts/6    S+   15:49   0:07 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/python3.4 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
ubuntu    9760  0.0  3.9 255840 39852 pts/6    S+   15:49   0:05 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/python3.4 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
ubuntu   12760  0.0  0.0  10464   932 pts/7    S+   19:04   0:00 grep --color=auto celery
```

Comment: try this `sudo ps auxww | grep celeryd | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -HUP`

Comment: Use the same command instead of `-HUP` use `-9` instead

Comment: No errors but process still running.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this in terminal

```
ps aux|grep 'celery worker'
```

You will see like this

```
username  29042  0.0  0.6  23216 14356 pts/1    S+   00:18   0:01 /bin/celery worker ...
```

Then kill process id by

```
sudo kill -9 process_id # here 29042
```

If you have multiple processes, then you have to kill all process id using above `kill` commmand

```
sudo kill -9 id1 id2 id3 ...
```

From the celery doc

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

OR if you are running `celeryd`

```
ps auxww | grep celeryd | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

**Note**

If you are running `celery` in `supervisor`, even though kill the process, it automatically restarts(if `autorestart=True` in supervisor script).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I tried (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep celery worker
grep: worker: No such file or directory

Comment: (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep 'celery worker' ->
ubuntu   12436  0.0  0.0  10460   936 pts/7    S+   18:45   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker

Comment: That means no celery worker is running?.Try `ps aux|grep celery`

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, and the detailed explanation. although I'm still working on my problem, you've given me some good information.

Comment: still problem? `sudo kill -9 9756 9760` ?

Comment: I asked a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319103/trouble-killing-celery-process

Comment: @itzMEonTV can you provide insight on how to perform these action remotely, also what if workers are running on Windows OS.

Answer (score 54):

```
pkill -f "celery worker"
```

easy to kill process by string patterns

Answer (score 42):

If the celery worker is running on a machine you do not have access to, you can use Celery "remote control" to control workers through messages sent via the broker.

`celery control shutdown`

This will kill *all* workers immediately. Depending on your setup, you might have to use `-A myProject`, like with Django.

Documentation [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/cli.html#celery-control).

Comment: Just FYI: This answer was flagged by someone as "low-quality" because of its length or content. This may be because there is no explaining text to accompany your suggested solution.

Comment: I don't get what `proj` is?

Comment: @KyleBridenstine proj is the name of you Application/Project, For instance if you application is Called DjangoApp the command wouyld be `celery -A DjangoApp control shutdown` from the root of your pjoject

Comment: This one worked for me. I tried killing celery workers by several other methods here. But `ps -eaf | grep celery` tells me that they didn't really work.

Answer (score 4):

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | grep -v " grep " | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

this one is very similar to one presented before but improved because avoid the error that shows when attempt to kill the grep process..

Comment: After trying all the others, this finally worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In case someone's looking to shutdown their celery app programmatically, the same thing can be done in python with:
`celery_app.control.shutdown()`