# Trouble killing celery process

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I am following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ along with the docs.

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

To start a worker. I have since made some changes to the Python, but realized that I need to restart a worker.

Following [How to stop celery worker process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306337/how-to-stop-celery-worker-process/29307816?noredirect=1#comment46829277_29307816) ,  I've tried:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep 'celery worker'
ubuntu    2033  0.0  0.0  10460   940 pts/11   S+   15:31   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ sudo kill -9 2033
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep 'celery worker'
ubuntu    2085  0.0  0.0  10460   940 pts/11   S+   15:32   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ sudo kill -9 2085
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep 'celery worker'
ubuntu    2129  0.0  0.0  10460   940 pts/11   S+   15:33   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker
```

I don't understand what is happening, it seems like a new one is created as I kill the old process?

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.5  36812  5972 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:02 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/u30:0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:01 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    Mar18   0:05 [rcuos/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/2]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/3]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/4]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/5]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/6]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/7]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/8]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/9]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/10]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/11]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/12]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/13]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuos/14]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/3]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/4]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/5]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/6]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/7]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/8]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/9]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/10]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/11]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/12]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/13]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [rcuob/14]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [migration/0]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:03 [watchdog/0]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [khelper]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [netns]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [xenwatch]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [xenbus]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    Mar18   0:10 [kworker/0:1]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [writeback]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [bioset]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kworker/u31:0]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kblockd]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [khubd]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [md]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar18   0:00 [ksmd]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Mar18   0:02 [khugepaged]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthre
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [crypto]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kworker/u30:1]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [khvcd]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [deferwq]
root       101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [charger_manage
root       142  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       203  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       204  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Mar18   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conve
root       311  0.0  0.4 105628  4184 ?        Ss   15:15   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu     370  0.0  0.1 105628  1884 ?        S    15:15   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@no
root       371  0.0  0.2  67896  2200 ?        Ss   15:15   0:00 sudo su -
root       372  0.0  0.1  63248  1772 ?        S    15:15   0:00 su -
root       373  0.0  0.1  19648  1792 ?        S    15:15   0:00 -su
root       411  0.0  0.1  49592  1272 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       536  0.0  0.4 105628  4208 ?        Ss   15:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
root       582  0.0  0.2  10224  2912 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 dhclient -1 -v
ubuntu     592  0.0  0.1 105628  1900 ?        S    15:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pt
ubuntu     593  0.0  0.4  22004  4612 pts/9    Ss+  15:16   0:00 -bash
root       627  0.0  0.4 105628  4216 ?        Ss   15:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu     683  0.0  0.1 105764  1900 ?        S    15:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pt
ubuntu     685  0.0  0.4  22020  4628 pts/10   Ss   15:16   0:00 -bash
ubuntu     738  0.0  2.9 102296 29512 ?        S    Mar24   0:06 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     742  0.0  2.4 102296 25152 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     743  0.0  2.4 102296 25152 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     744  0.0  2.4 102296 25152 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     754  0.0  2.9 102368 29500 ?        S    Mar24   0:06 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     758  0.0  2.4 102368 25148 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     759  0.0  2.4 102368 25148 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     760  0.0  2.4 102368 25148 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     788  0.0  2.9 102344 29496 ?        S    Mar24   0:06 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     792  0.0  2.4 102344 25144 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     793  0.0  2.4 102344 25144 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu     794  0.0  2.4 102344 25144 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
root       803  0.0  0.4 105628  4172 ?        Ss   15:17   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu     854  0.0  2.9 102292 30088 ?        S    Mar24   0:06 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu     861  0.0  0.1 105628  1880 ?        S    15:17   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@no
ubuntu     864  0.0  0.0  12820   912 ?        Ss   15:17   0:00 /usr/lib/openss
message+   905  0.0  0.1  39224  1160 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 dbus-daemon --s
root       925  0.0  0.1  43452  1608 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
syslog     984  0.0  1.1 260272 11820 ?        Ssl  Mar18   0:02 rsyslogd
root      1025  0.0  0.0  14540   760 tty4     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1028  0.0  0.0  14540   756 tty5     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1032  0.0  0.0  14540   764 tty2     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1033  0.0  0.0  14540   764 tty3     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1035  0.0  0.0  14540   760 tty6     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1069  0.0  0.2  61364  2904 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:04 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1092  0.0  0.0   4368   552 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 acpid -c /etc/a
root      1093  0.0  0.0  23656   900 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 cron
daemon    1094  0.0  0.0  19140   164 ?        Ss   Mar18   0:00 atd
root      1101  0.0  0.1  85868  1384 ?        Ss   15:20   0:00 nginx: master p
www-data  1104  0.0  0.1  86176  1808 ?        S    15:20   0:00 nginx: worker p
www-data  1105  0.0  0.1  86176  1808 ?        S    15:20   0:00 nginx: worker p
www-data  1106  0.0  0.1  86176  1808 ?        S    15:20   0:00 nginx: worker p
www-data  1107  0.0  0.2  86548  2648 ?        S    15:20   0:00 nginx: worker p
ubuntu    1115  0.0  2.9 102348 30092 pts/10   S+   15:20   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    1120  0.0  3.4 109768 35000 pts/10   S+   15:20   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    1121  0.0  2.4 102348 25148 pts/10   S+   15:20   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    1122  0.0  3.4 109760 34956 pts/10   S+   15:20   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
root      1164  0.0  0.0  14540   768 tty1     Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1165  0.0  0.0  12788   724 ttyS0    Ss+  Mar18   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 [kauditd]
ubuntu    1549  0.0  3.3 108960 33780 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    1550  0.0  3.3 108960 33776 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    1551  0.0  2.4 102292 25144 ?        S    Mar24   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
root      1599  0.0  0.0  19472   384 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 upstart-udev-br
root      1602  0.0  0.0  15272   384 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 upstart-file-br
root      1605  0.0  0.0  15256   388 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 upstart-socket-
root      1842  0.0  0.4 105628  4220 ?        Ss   15:30   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu    1899  0.0  0.1 105628  1900 ?        S    15:30   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pt
ubuntu    1901  0.0  0.4  21988  4596 pts/11   Ss   15:30   0:00 -bash
root      2210  0.0  0.3  62704  3100 ?        Ss   15:34   0:00 sshd: [accepted
sshd      2211  0.0  0.1  62704  1368 ?        S    15:34   0:00 sshd: [net]
ubuntu    2212  0.0  0.1  17164  1324 pts/11   R+   15:34   0:00 ps aux
ubuntu    3430  0.0  2.9 102288 30084 ?        S    Mar25   0:04 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    3457  0.0  2.4 102288 25140 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    3458  0.0  2.4 102288 25140 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    3459  0.0  2.4 102288 25140 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
redis     3932  0.0  0.7  38564  7116 ?        Ssl  Mar25   0:59 /usr/bin/redis-
ubuntu    3963  0.0  2.9 102296 30092 ?        S    Mar25   0:04 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    4247  0.0  2.4 102296 25144 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    4248  0.0  2.4 102296 25144 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    4249  0.0  2.4 102296 25144 ?        S    Mar25   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu    7360  0.0  2.9 102380 29508 ?        S    Mar26   0:05 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    7364  0.0  3.3 109264 34044 ?        S    Mar26   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    7365  0.0  3.3 109264 34044 ?        S    Mar26   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu    7366  0.0  3.3 109204 33864 ?        S    Mar26   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu   10272  0.0  2.9 102284 30076 ?        S    Mar27   0:03 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13160  0.0  2.4 102284 25132 ?        S    Mar27   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13161  0.0  2.4 102284 25132 ?        S    Mar27   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13162  0.0  2.4 102284 25132 ?        S    Mar27   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13875  0.0  2.9 102292 30088 ?        S    01:39   0:02 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13968  0.0  3.2 108332 33040 ?        S    03:56   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13969  0.0  2.4 102292 25144 ?        S    03:56   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   13970  0.0  2.4 102292 25144 ?        S    03:56   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   19155  0.0  2.6  84856 27160 ?        S    Mar20   0:17 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   19202  0.0  2.3  85248 23908 ?        S    Mar20   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   19203  0.0  2.2  84856 22444 ?        S    Mar20   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
ubuntu   19204  0.0  2.3  85248 23908 ?        S    Mar20   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.v
root     29838  0.0  0.4 105628  4176 ?        Ss   14:43   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu   29919  0.0  0.1 105628  1880 ?        S    14:43   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@no
root     29920  0.0  0.2  67896  2200 ?        Ss   14:43   0:00 sudo su -
root     29921  0.0  0.1  63248  1772 ?        S    14:43   0:00 su -
root     29922  0.0  0.1  19648  1792 ?        S    14:43   0:00 -su
root     30070  0.0  0.4 105628  4172 ?        Ss   14:45   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu   30125  0.0  0.1 105628  1728 ?        S    14:45   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@no
ubuntu   30126  0.0  0.0  12820   916 ?        Ss   14:45   0:00 /usr/lib/openss
root     30369  0.0  0.4 105628  4212 ?        Ss   14:48   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu   30424  0.0  0.1 105764  1904 ?        S    14:48   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pt
ubuntu   30425  0.0  0.4  22020  4632 pts/7    Ss   14:48   0:00 -bash
root     30795  0.0  0.4 105628  4220 ?        Ss   14:52   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [p
ubuntu   30853  0.0  0.1 105628  1904 ?        S    14:52   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pt
ubuntu   30871  0.0  0.4  21896  4172 pts/8    Ss+  14:52   0:00 -bash
ubuntu   31044  0.0  2.9 102288 30092 pts/7    S+   14:53   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu   31050  0.0  2.4 102288 25144 pts/7    S+   14:53   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu   31051  0.0  2.4 102288 25144 pts/7    S+   14:53   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
ubuntu   31052  0.0  3.5 110276 35744 pts/7    S+   14:53   0:00 uwsgi --ini uws
root     32412  0.0  1.1  53660 11228 ?        Ss   Mar24   0:42 /usr/bin/python
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$
```

Comment: just put `ps aux|grep celery` only

Comment: (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ ps aux|grep 'celery'
ubuntu    3678  0.0  0.0  10460   936 pts/11   S+   15:56   0:00 grep --color=auto celery

Comment: You are running `celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO` na ?.Then just `Ctrl + C` only need to kill worker?

Comment: Yes! that worked. Thank you. Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it? Also,  I think this process has been running for days. why was the process number changing and why did "sudo kill -9 process_id" not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `celery worker` like

```
celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

To kill the process, Just `Ctrl + C`

Comment: Yes! that worked. Thank you.  I think this process has been running for days. why was the process number changing and why did "sudo kill -9 process_id" not work?

Comment: you posted, `ubuntu    2033  0.0  0.0  10460   940 pts/11   S+   15:31   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker`, That is not the celery process, it is the process running for `grep` in `ps aux |grep ...`.Thats why it always changing when you execute the command.If the `celery` process is running, you can find something like `/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker`.You can kill that process ids.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, I've asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319889/how-to-list-of-the-queued-items-in-celery if you wouldn't mind looking.