# How to list the queued items in celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I am following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ along with the docs.

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

I just realized, that I have a bunch of tasks in my queue, that had not executed:

```
[2015-03-28 16:49:05,916: WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 4 unacknowledged message(s).
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery -A tp purge
WARNING: This will remove all tasks from queue: celery.
         There is no undo for this operation!

(to skip this prompt use the -f option)

Are you sure you want to delete all tasks (yes/NO)? yes
Purged 81 messages from 1 known task queue.
```

How do I get a list of the queued items from the command line?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to get all scheduled tasks,

```
celery inspect scheduled
```

To find all active queues

```
celery inspect active_queues
```

For status

```
celery inspect stats
```

For all commands

```
celery inspect
```

If you want to get it explicitily.Since you are using `redis` as queue.Then

```
redis-cli

>KEYS * #find all keys
```

Then find out something related to `celery`

```
>LLEN KEY # i think it gives length of list
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error with this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331280/connection-refused-with-celery

Comment: I have a follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377944/trouble-installing-supervisord-with-celery, if you are bored.

Comment: Another follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402447/how-to-set-celeryconfig-file-in-in-django

Comment: This is useful information, but doesn't really answer the question. I'm, too, interested in listing all task in the queue. Reading man pages and --help from celery, I've found those commands, but they only list tasks either scheduled, active or reserved. If you consider non-scheduled tasks (eta/count), the bunch of tasks are just waiting in the queue. The redis stuff is kinda hacky, and doesn't provide any information beside the number of such tasks. Is that just not possible with celery ???

Answer (score 14):

Here is a copy-paste solution for Redis:

```
def get_celery_queue_len(queue_name):
    from yourproject.celery import app as celery_app
    with celery_app.pool.acquire(block=True) as conn:
        return conn.default_channel.client.llen(queue_name)


def get_celery_queue_items(queue_name):
    import base64
    import json
    from yourproject.celery import app as celery_app

    with celery_app.pool.acquire(block=True) as conn:
        tasks = conn.default_channel.client.lrange(queue_name, 0, -1)

    decoded_tasks = []

    for task in tasks:
        j = json.loads(task)
        body = json.loads(base64.b64decode(j['body']))
        decoded_tasks.append(body)

    return decoded_tasks
```

It works with Django. Just don't forget to change `yourproject.celery`.

Comment: How do you know what the queue name is?

Comment: @Trent the default queue name is "celery".

Comment: Thanks, I wondered what was wrong with my celery.  It turns out I had 57,000 tasks queued from a bug last week.