# 'connection refused' with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I am following [How to list the queued items in celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319889/how-to-list-of-the-queued-items-in-celery) along with the docs, to experiment with celery at the command line.

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

However, if I run other celery commands like below I'm getting the following:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery inspect ping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 307, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in run_from_argv
    sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 373, in handle_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 324, in run
    return self.do_call_method(args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 346, in do_call_method
    callback=self.say_remote_command_reply)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 385, in call
    return getattr(i, method)(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 100, in ping
    return self._request('ping')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 71, in _request
    timeout=self.timeout, reply=True,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 307, in broadcast
    limit, callback, channel=channel,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 283, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 756, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 112, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
OSError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The installed python packages:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ pip freeze
amqp==1.4.6
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.19
celery==3.1.17
Django==1.7.7
django-redis-cache==0.13.0
kombu==3.0.24
pytz==2015.2
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.6.0
uWSGI==2.0.10
```

/projects/tp/tp/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tp.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('hello_django')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

also , in redis.conf:

```
# Specify the path for the unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
  unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
  unixsocketperm 777
```

tp.settings.py:

```
# CELERY SETTINGS
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    },
}
```

edit 2:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ redis-cli ping
PONG
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ service redis-server status
redis-server is not running
```

edit 3:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ redis-cli ping
PONG
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ sudo service redis-server start
Starting redis-server: failed
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ service redis-server status
redis-server is not running
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this add it to `project/__init__.py` it should work, app is always imported so  shared_task can use this app

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using `rabbitmq` as queue.So check

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server status
```

if stop,

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

Comment: (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
rabbitmq-server: unrecognized service--I was trying to set this up with redis following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/

Comment: Can you show the clery configurations such as BROKER URL, etc ?

Comment: k can you check redis is working, service redis-server status?

Comment: start it, if installed.Otherwise install redis-server

Comment: sudo apt-get install redis-server

Comment: Sorry, I already did that following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/